# No boot command on Cisco 3925

Tags: cisco, boot, downgrade

I had to downgrade a couple of Cisco 3925 routers last week and one of the steps in the [instructions](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-24033) (link provided) was to change the boot command that was given by the following command:

```
Cisco-3925# show run | include boot
```

The downgrade went fine, but what I'd like to know is why this command didn't show any boot instruction before the downgrade was successful. Here is the output of that command:

```
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
```

How did the router boot before the downgrade in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no boot command specified, by default the router loads the first IOS image that it finds in flash, alphanumerically. If you have 2 IOS images on your flash drive the rooter will boot the oldest IOS version that it finds (typically).

Comment: Why does it use the older one?

Comment: It goes in alphabetical then numerical order. So if you have 12.1.0 and 12.1.1 on the drive it will use the older 12.1.0 image.